# How to skip Initialization Scripts when executing gradle build

Tags: gradle

I'm new to Gradle and im trying to build my project on a CentOS machine that is being used to build other projects as well. In the USER_HOME/.gradle/init.d/ there are some initialization scripts that are executed before every gradlebuild command. However they break my build and i want to skip them but i dont want to delete them or affect the other builds. Is there any way to run gradle build with something like a "skip initilization" flag

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to skip, an init script. For a moment I thought that `-I` switch covers the script located under `$HOME` or `GRADLE_HOME` but this is not the case.

It seems that the only way to go is to have a separate installation of gradle without init scripts. Wrapper, also won't help since init scripts are invoked with wrapper as well - which is correct and expected behaviour.